# When the magnetic force is perpendicular to the velocity what will be affected on a charge?

Tags: forces, electricity

I guess it can also be stated as a two part question. Is the velocity of a charge always perpendicular to the magnetic force, and when the magnetic force is perpendicular to the velocity what is affected on a charge?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?  "Which would make this answer its direction" means what, exactly?

Comment: I guess it can also be stated as a two part question.  Is the velocity of a charge always perpendicular to the magnetic force, and when the magnetic force is perpendicular to the velocity what is affected on a charge?

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.  You can edit the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force on a moving charge is the [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force)

$$\vec F = q (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$$

The "magnetic force" (which is not a Lorentz-invariant term, since electric fields in one reference frame will be magnetic fields in others and vice versa) in a narrow sense is just $q (\vec v \times \vec B)$, which is indeed *always* orthogonal to the velocity of the charge since the cross product produces a vector that point in the direction of the normal vector of the plane spanned by $\vec v$ and $\vec B$.

Note that the *force* and the *velocity* are not independent vectors that just happen to be orthogonal - the force directly *depends* on the velocity in a way that forces it to be orthogonal.